# Formulário de Contato - Envio de data 0000-00-00

Tags: php, html, formulário, input, data

Bom dia, fiz um formulário de contato e coloquei um  mas quando eu coloco a data certinho exemplo: 31/08/2017, clico em enviar a data vem como: 2017/08/31, gostaria de deixar como padrão do Brasil.

Meu input:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" name="datadenascimento" id="datadenascimento" class="gui-input" placeholder="Data de Nascimento">
```

A string que faz o envio:

```
$datadenascimento = strip_tags(trim($_POST["datadenascimento"]));
```

Comment: Só uma dica. O mais recomendado é usar trim(strip_tags($_POST["datadenascimento"]));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o "date_formate" do próprio php!

```
$data = $_POST['datadenascimento'];
$data_cria = new DateTime($data);

$data_formata = $data_cria->format('d/m/Y');
```

[Leia mais aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.format.php)

Comment: Está dando o seguinte erro: Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface

Comment: Desculpe. Erro meu. Já arrumei! Confira agora!

Comment: Coloquei mas ainda continuar chegando como: "Data de Nascimento: 2017-11-30"

Comment: Tem como me mostrar o código final? Por que aqui está funcionando: http://cartola.ml/teste.php